# scss file from node_modules makes error in React js

Tags: material-design

I am using [Google Material design](https://material.io/develop/web/)  with React js app. for using scss, i've added `node-sass` as per [documention](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/). It's working fine for local `.scss` file, but when i trying to import from node_modules, it produces errors!
i've tried `@import "@material/button/mdc-button"`, then `@import "~@material/button/mdc-button"` both. it produce

```
SassError: Invalid CSS after "@include mixins": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".core-styles;"
        on line 24 of node_modules/@material/button/mdc-button.scss
        from line 1 of D:\workspace\react\sass-react\src\App.scss
>> @include mixins.core-styles;

   ---------^
```

How can i solve this?

**note:** also added `.env` file as per that doc.